# Why does the size of a div element change when changing position from fixed to absolute?

Tags: html, css, size, css-position

I have a div containing some text. This div used to be `position:fixed`, but for some reasons I need it to be `position:absolute`.

However, when changing it from fixed to static its size changed (the "auto-sizing" during `fixed` display was nice and should be preserved).

Here's a minimal example: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/yBRa9/3/

I'm looking for a way to keep `position:absolute` without the element shrinking to the lowest possible size.

Using JavaScript it's [easy to achieve](http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/yBRa9/8/) but if it could be done without additional JS it would be nice.

Comment: Are you looking to resize the division, based on the contents inside?

Comment: I'd like the div to be sized in the same way like the one with `position:fixed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here Check it.](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/yBRa9/9/) I used a span with `inline-block`, seems to do what you want <sub>(Of course, If I had understood your question properly)</sub>.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn’t work when the popup is positioned absolutely, which is I think what the OP requires.

Comment: @Paul, even with `position:absolute` the span behaves the same way.

Comment: It seems to work. At least for my testcase. Unfortunately one of the more complex dialogs in my app is still broken but hopefully I'll get that fixed - if not I'll have to use JS to set a width :/

Comment: oh really? Sorry, I changed it in the JSFiddle and it seemed to go back to the default behaviour; must have mistyped something.

Answer (score 1):

elements with absolute positioning doesn't inherit the parent's width. You will have to set `width` or `min-width`

Comment: This CSS is used for various dialogs. Setting widths for all of them would be pretty much work. I need dynamic sizing depending on its contents.

Comment: Developers have to do work?  heaven forfend *grin*.  One trick I used to use in the olden days ... put an image at the top of the block, with a width of say 300px ... height 1px, transparent GIF ... that'll force the minimum width to be something reasonable, but if something in there is larger than that, it can expand to accommodate it.  If you don't care about IE6 compatibility, you can just use min-width.

Comment: For this reason I could use `min-width`. I had that fix and it worked fine for small dialogs. But some larger ones are still broken - and I don't want to set a high `min-width` as that would make those smaller dialogs look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I read Teneff's answer and fixed it by setting width: 100%. Not confident if this is the best way to do things because I am new. Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div id="slider">   
<div class="slide">
                    <div class="slide-copy">
                        <h2>Slide</h2>
                        <p>Sliding time</p>                     
                    </div>
                    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/spring-clip-art-spring-clip-art.jpg" alt="an image">
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider {
    width: 940px;
    height: 350px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    border: #666 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.slide-copy {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #7f7f7f;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```